# MongoDB : How can I project all field types for a single document?

Tags: mongodb, types, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to check every single field type in every document on a given collection.

While I can write the individual `$type` commands for each field and match for each document separately, I am wondering if there is a more elegant and efficient way to just project all the field types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        types: {
            $arrayToObject: {
            $map:
            {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                as: "each",
                in: { k: '$$each.k', v: { $type: '$$each.v' } }
            }
        }}
    }
}])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e065992400289966eefb9a8"),
    "username" : "myName",
    "blog" : "myBlog",
    "details" : "myBlogDetails",
    "Object" : {
        "inOneObject" : true
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0659ae400289966eefbc3a"),
    "username" : "othersName",
    "blog" : "not a blog",
    "details" : "useless"
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e065992400289966eefb9a8"),
    "username" : "myName",
    "blog" : "myBlog",
    "details" : "myBlogDetails",
    "Object" : {
        "inObject" : true
    },
    "types" : {
        "_id" : "objectId",
        "username" : "string",
        "blog" : "string",
        "details" : "string",
        "Object" : "object"
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0659ae400289966eefbc3a"),
    "username" : "othersName",
    "blog" : "not a blog",
    "details" : "useless",
    "types" : {
        "_id" : "objectId",
        "username" : "string",
        "blog" : "string",
        "details" : "string"
    }
}
```

**Note :** This given query would work only for top level fields in the document, it won't get you type of `inObject` from below field ::

```
"Object" : {
            "inOneObject" : true
        }
```

Comment: This might just be right for my needs. Thank you both.

Comment: @Ben : Hey can you please accept this that way your question will be marked as complete with a working answer..

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to enumerate all of the fields and handle each one individually. You can do this with a combination of `$objectToArray` and `$unwind` for the purposes of enumeration, and then `$push` and `$arrayToObject` for grouping everything back together:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Convert the root document into an array.
    {$project: {
        fields: {
            $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }},

    // Turn each array element into a separate document representing a field-value pair of the root document.
    {$unwind: "$fields"},

    // Apply the $type projection to the value portion of the field-value pair.
    {$project: {
        fields: {
            k: "$fields.k",
            v: {$type: "$fields.v"}
        }
    }},

    // Grab the first instance of each unique field name.
    {$group: {
        _id: "$fields.k",
        fields: {$first: "$fields"}
    }},

    // Take the unique field instances and recollect them all into an array.
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        fields: {$push: "$fields"}
    }},

    // Convert our array back into an object.
    {$project: {
        fields: {$arrayToObject: "$fields"}
    }},

    // Replace the root document with our nested "fields" sub-document.
    {$replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$fields"
    }}
])
```

A small caveat: if the field may contain multiple types, e.g. "string" and "null", then this solution won't account for this case. To fix that problem, you'll want to modify the `$group` stages to utilize an `$addToSet` operator to collect the unique `$type` instances for each key before `$push`ing them into the `fields` array.

Comment: Or if you want to exclude nulls from the list altogether (since for "optional" values typically it'll be a specific type or null, and knowing that some of the values is "null" isn't particularly useful) you could add a filter for that: `{$match: {"fields.v": {$ne:null}}}, // After $unwind`.

Answer (score -2):

have you tried using the mongo Compass product?

this would be easy I believe for this requirement.....